# How To send a RSTP stream with the newest FFmpeg(NOT BY COMMAND)

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

Can any body give me a example or indicate to use FFmpeg library to capture the USB video (or capture the internet RSTP stream )and send the information to our own server by RTSP stream.Very Thanks your answer

Comment: And I find some examples on inertnet,but because they didn't use the newest ffmpeg library,item can't be very useful

Comment: Could you show what you've at least tried? (and why it doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks ,I have already solved it -_-

Comment: Could you add answer to your question so that people who have the same issue can benefit?